# Load Data from a table on one server's database, to the same table structure in multiple server databases

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dynamic-sql

I have a situation where i have to load data from one server/database table to multiple servers/databases.

Example:

Using SSIS, I need to load data from dbo.TABLE_A  (on Server: Server_A & Database: Database_A)  to the same table on the list of server databases like

Server: Server_B , Database: Database_B

Server: Server_C , Database: Database_C

Server: Server_D , Database: Database_D

Server: Server_E , Database: Database_E

Server: Server_F , Database: Database_F

Server: Server_G , Database: Database_G

Server: Server_H , Database: Database_H

so on and so forth on 250 such server database combinations.

The table structure is the same on all the servers.

If i make the source or destination dynamic, it throws an error while mapping ?

I cannot get Linked server permissions and SQL Server Config thing doesn't work as well.

Please suggest on how to load data from one source to multiple server/databases.

Thank you.

Comment: Just one table or many tables need to be synchronized across these servers? Are their foreign key relationships? Do we need to do change detection or is the data append only? Can we truncate and reload the target? When we start exporting data, does the data need to match across all the servers (a snapshot of the data) or is it acceptable that data hitting server 230-250 has one more row of data because the source changed during the run?

Comment: I just need to sync one table, its like i have to use a query to pick data for the most recent data. So i use something like, select A, B, C, D from dbo.table where ETL_TIMESTAMP > (the max(etltimestamp) in the destination on different server). There are no foreign key relationships and the data should not be truncated. it just had to append the new records. The data should match.

Comment: When you say `ETL_TIMESTAMP > (the max(etltimestamp) in the destination on different server)`, does that condition need to be computed for **each** destination server or only once per package run because each server holds the same data?

Comment: actually we compute it each time, just to be sure.

Comment: I fixed the issue by using package configurations (SQL Server Config). I put an execute sql task (to update server db details of ssis config table) in a for loop container and linked it data flow task. So when everytime the loop executes the execute sql task is updating ssis config table to update connection strings used by data flow tasks. that did the trick to me. i will soon post the solution. thank you.